# Get Child item not coming back true

Tags: powershell

I am trying to return a boolean for a specific file within a directory from within a script when I use the first command within the local directory it works and the function seeing a file returns True, and my statement launches.

```
get-childitem *agc.txt
```

Once I move back one directory the function no longer works.

```
get-childitem -path test -include agc.txt
```

The end result is to have networked paths.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why function 1 work within the local directory but function 2 does not when I cd into a different directory

Comment: Use `get-childitem test\file.ext` or just `get-item`

Comment: cool so just dont use the include function

Comment: yes, the behavior of `-include` and `-exclude` can be confusing sometimes. the linked duplicate gives context and background

Comment: To piggyback off @SantiagoSquarzon ``Test-Path`` is for checking if something exits or not. It automatically returns a ``Boolean`` value

Answer (score 0):

The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the contents of an item, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2

So do:

```
get-childitem -path test* -include agc.txt
```

and you get agc.txt. To get any file ending with agc.txt, specify *agc.txt.